# android studio canvas in a class

Tags: android, class, canvas

I've been working on a game for Android in Android Studio.  But I'm newish to Java and to Android Studio, and I want to clean up the code by creating classes for the logical parts of the game.  My goal for the last couple of days is to get the Draw class to do all the screen drawing work which will consist of bitmap manipulation and drawText statements.

However I can't even seem to get my Canvas to initialize. I've tired all sorts of solutions referred to in other questions on this site, but none of them relate to setting up the Canvas in a class.  My gut tells my I am missing something in the Draw constructor, but I can't work it out.

At the moment the code compiles just fine, but when it runs, its just a black screen.  The test is just to display the fps on the top left corner of the screen.

The main class is ClassDrawTest

```
package com.example.jochum.classdrawtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class ClassDrawTest extends Activity {



 GameView gameView;

    long fps;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        gameView = new GameView(this);
        setContentView(gameView);
    } // end of onCreate

    class GameView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {
        Update Update = new Update();
        Draw Draw = new Draw();
        volatile boolean playing = true;
        private long timeThisFrame;


        public GameView(Context context) {
            super(context);


        } //end of GameView constructor

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (playing) {

                // Capture the current time in milliseconds in startFrameTime
                long startFrameTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                // Update the frame
                Update.update();

                // Draw the frame
                Draw.draw();

                // Calculate the fps this frame
                // We can then use the result to
                // time animations and more.
                timeThisFrame = System.currentTimeMillis() - startFrameTime;
                if (timeThisFrame > 0) {
                    fps = 1000 / timeThisFrame;
                } // end of if (timeThisFrame)
            }// end of while (playing) loop
        } // end of run() method
    } // end of GameView Class

    //Getters and Setters
    public long getFps(){
        return fps;
    }
} // end of ClassDrawTest Class
```

Then the Draw class which I want the canvas to be part of.

```
package com.example.jochum.classdrawtest;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

public class Draw {

    ClassDrawTest ClassDrawTest = new ClassDrawTest();

    Canvas canvas;
    Paint paint;
    SurfaceHolder ourHolder;

    public Draw() {

    } // end constructor Draw

    public void draw() {

        // get fps from ClassDrawTest class
        long fps = ClassDrawTest.getFps();
        // Make sure our drawing surface is valid or we crash
        if (ourHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
            // Lock the canvas ready to draw
            canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();

         // Debug code
            // Draw the background color
            canvas.drawColor(Color.argb(255, 26, 128, 182));           
            paint.setColor(Color.argb(255, 249, 129, 0));
            paint.setTextSize(45);

            // Display the current fps on the screen
            canvas.drawText("FPS:" + fps, 20, 40, paint);

            ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

        } //end if ourHolder
    } //end method draw
} //end class Draw
```

The manifest file sets it up as landscape view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.jochum.classdrawtest">

<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <activity android:name=".ClassDrawTest">
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: The Runnable should be run(). You need to do this manually. I believe you will have other issues too, but lets first handle this one.

Comment: Thank you so much for you response!  I thought the Runnable was run().   I feel I'm still missing quite a bit of the basic logic of Java.  If its not to much trouble could you show me a bit of code as an example.  Again thanks for taking the time to help!

Comment: You can take a look at a great guide I've found - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UH2OWnq7NQ4 ,where the run method is called by a constructor for a new Thread. You'll see.